# Gnuplottex axis format

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplottex

I cant get proper format axis, I get the following code to gnuplot in my tex project:

```
set yrange [0:1]            
set mytics 5
set ytics 0,.5,1
```

And I get this:

[image]

but however when I tag tics on this way:

```
set yrange [0:1]            
set mytics 5
set ytics ("0.0"0,"0.5".5,"1.0"1)
```

mtics divisions disappear and I would like to preserve them:

[image]

Is there anyway to format axis labels in gnuplottex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplottex doesn't format anything itself; all the formatting is done by gnuplot. You can find information on how to format labls with gnuplot [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html).

Comment: Yes, what I wanted was specifically `set format y '%.1t'; set ytics 0,.5,1 ` but thank  you so much for your help.